# Total number of common factors for two numbers LARGE VALUES upto 10^12

Tags: c++, performance

Inputs are two values 1 <= m , n <= 10^12
i don't know why my code is taking soo long for large values . time limit is 1 sec. please suggest me some critical modifications.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
unsigned long long m,n,count=0;
cin >> m >> n;  
for (long long int i = 1; i <= ((min(m,n))/2)+1; i++) //i divided min(m,n) by 2 to make it efficient.
{

    if ((m%i == 0) && (n%i == 0))
    {
        count++;
    }

}
if (((n%m == 0) || (m%n == 0)) && (n!=m))
{
    cout << count << endl;
}

printf("%lld",count);  //cout<<count;

system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Removed the Java and C tags, please don't add tag spam to your question. It's going to attract the wrong kind of attention.

Comment: If this is working code that you want improvement suggestions for then the question is more appropriate for [codereview.se].

Comment: C users can equally help

Comment: @AshutoshMalla Bike riders can help too. But it doesn't mean you tag it with #bikeriders. Only use the language tag that the code is written in. Answers can differ significantly depending on the language.

Comment: Tagging this with everything under the sun wastes people's time. Giving people crap for telling you how the sites works takes a lot of nerve, too. C is not C++. C does not have Boost.

Comment: /2 is good start, but not enough. You only need to test numbers up to square root to find all factors of a number (just do not forget that if x is a factor of n, also n/x is a factor of n).

Comment: 10^12 is also a pretty damned big number. How many supercomputers are you intending to run this code on in order for a trillion loops to complete in one second?

Comment: wow , Thanks @Antonin , i will try this

Comment: In all seriousness, you need to read up on [integer factorization algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization) because obviously this attack is not going to succeed. This is like the Bubble Sort of factoring algorithms, there's significantly better approaches. Find one that you feel comfortable implementing and give it a shot to see how it works out.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because working code might be reviewed on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: And you also should work on your **expectations**. Coming here, not understanding our rules and practices, and then ... you **expect** us to help you? Do you really think this motivates people to help you? Besides: tadman is spot on - it is really not like you are the first person trying to do this. How much time did you spent on doing research before writing up your code or this question?

Comment: @AntonínLejsek , it really worked . THANKS SOO MUCH !

Answer (score 3):

Firstly

```
((min(m, n)) / 2) + 1
```

Is being calculated every iteration. But it's loop-invariant. In general loop invariant code can be calculated before the loop, and stored. It will add up, but there are obviously much better ways to improve things. I'll describe one below:

you can make this much faster by calculating how many common prime factors there are, and by dividing out any "found" primes as you go. e.g. if only one number is divisible by 5, and the other is not, you can divide that one by 5 and you still get the same answer for common factors. Divide m and n by any "found" numbers as you go through it. (but keep checking whether either is divisible by e.g. 2 and keep dividing before you go on).

e.g. if the two numbers are both divisible by 2, 3 and 5, then the number of ways those three primes can combine is 8 (2^3), treating the presence of each prime as a true/false thing. So each prime that occurs once multiplies the number of combos by 2.

If any of the primes occurs more than once, then it changes the equation slightly. e.g. if the two numbers are divisible by 4, 3, 5:

4 = 2^2, so you could have no "2s", 1 "2" or 2 "2s" in the combined factor, so the total combinations 3 x 2 x 2 = 12. So any prime that occurs "x" times, multiplies the total number of combos by "x+1".

So basically, you don't need to check for every actual factor, you just need to search for how many common prime factors there are, then work out how many combos that adds up to. Luckily you only need to store one value, "total_combos" and multiply it by the "x+1" value for each found number as you go.

And a handy thing is that you can divide out all primes as they're found, and you're guaranteed that the largest remaining prime to be found is no larger than the square root of the smallest remaining number out of m and n.

So to run you through how this would work, start with a copy of m and n, loop up to the sqrt of the min of those two (m and n will be reduced as the loop cycles through).

make a value "total_combos", which starts at 1.

Check for 2's first, find out how many common powers of 2 there are, add one to that number. Divide out ALL the 2's from m and n, even if they're not matched, because reducing down the number cuts the total amount you actually need to search. You count the 2's, add one, then multiply "total_combos" by that. Keep dividing m or n by two as long as either has a factor of 2 remaining.

Then check for 3's, find out how many common powers of 3 there are, add one, the multiply "total_combos" by that. Divide out any and all factors of 3 when you're doing this.

then check for 4's. Since 4 isn't prime and we got rid of all 2's already, there will be zero 4's. Add one to that = 1, then we times "total_combos" by 1, so it stays the same. We didn't need to check whether 4 was prime or not, the divisions we already did ensured it's ignored. Same for any power of 2.

then check for 5's. same deal as 2's and 3's. And so on. All the prime bases get divided out as you go, so whenever a value actually matches you can be sure it's a new prime.

stop the loop when it exceeds sqrt(max(m,n)) (EDITED: min is probably wrong there).  But m and n here are the values that have had all the lower primes divided out, so it's much faster.

I hope this approach is helpful.

Comment: THATS VERY HELPFUL , THANKS @Jason-Lang

Comment: Ah one caveat, sqrt(min(m,n)) could fail if one of them has a high prime number. e.g. if m is itself prime, e.g. 97, then you want to check at least up to 97, as long as n >= 97 * 97. So you probably want to check sqrt(max(m,n)) as the cut-off point, not min

Comment: btw note that you can also speed this up further by researching ways to list all the primes up to a certain number, you can use those tricks to skip numbers that can't be prime. basically you make a "next_prime" function, which does the search for primes in that function, and instead of a for loop, you do a while loop that keeps looping until the returned "next_prime" value is greater than m or n (keep reducing down m and n though by dividing out all prime factors as you go to short-circuit it as much as possible).

Comment: sqrt(min(m,n)) is correct. You only have to test if the last prime ramainder divides the other number, that is a special case. sqrt(max(m,n)) does not handle that in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way to solve this problem.
All you have to do is  take the ***GCD of  two  numbers***. Now  any number won't divide m & n if they are greater than their GCD. So all you  to  do is that run a loop till the **i<=Math.sqrt(GCD(m,n))** and check if the m%i==0 and n%i==0 only. It will save a lot of nanosecs.